# Need to pull fields from an issue in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, api, soap, sitecore

I'm working with SiteCore and I need to pull some data out of the software via either that API or the SQL database using a PHP script.  The reason I say both are possible is because even if the database changes later on, that doesn't matter to me.

Anyway...

I'm trying to pull any data fields that I can get from a particular issue.  This is my SOAP code so far, and it connects to the service and such, but the return isn't what I need...

```
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8083/sitecore/shell/webservice/service.asmx?WSDL');

    $credentials = array('Password' => 'mypassword','Username' => 'sitecore\myusername');

    $Current_Issue = array(
    'id' => '{043B69BA-3175-4184-812F-C925CE80324E}',
    //'language' => 'en',
    //'version' => '1',
    //'allFields' => 'true',
    'databaseName' => 'web',
    'credentials' => $credentials
    );

    $response = $client->GetItemMasters($Current_Issue);
    print_r($response);

}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is my output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetItemMastersResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => <sitecore xmlns=""/>
        )

)
```

ANY help is appreciated.  If anybody knows an example SQL query that I can use, that would be just as useful as an alternative method.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running Sitecore 6.5 / 6.6 you may want to take a look at the Sitecore Item Web API which was released yesterday (5/11/12).

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API.aspx

This allows you to perform RESTful operations against Sitecore items without the need for the old web service / SOAP interface. Using this module you can receive a JSON representation of a Sitecore item or collection of items and even post back changes. You may find it easier to work with :)

If you have to use the SOAP interface, are you sure that your items are published ? Try changing the databaseName -> 'master' and see if you get any results. Other things to check are the permissions of the user credentials you are using.